# Quickest way to count number of unique values per key?

Tags: python, dictionary, count

I have a text file with two column name|familyname in which a name can have different family so, we have multiple rows with same name and different familynames. The file is around50GB. What I want is the number of familynames per name.

currently I created a dictionary in with names as keys and family name as values, and I am printing out each key and length of the value (as a set of family names). But this is not really efficient and quick

```
d = defaultdict(set)


f = open(file, 'r')
for n, line in enumerate(f):
    name,family= line.split('|')
    d[name].add(family)


for name, family in d.iteritems():
    print("%s|%s" % (name, len(family)), file = w)
```

Does any body have any suggestion for a quicker method of getting the same result?

Comment: 50gb of text? How many lines does this file has? Just curious.

Comment: In your shell: wc -l <filename>

Comment: yeah I know but it would take a lot of time also and how is that useful?

Comment: Anyway, unless you inject such file into a database, you'll have to go through each line and then do as you do. It will takes ages as the file is too huge for optimal computation. IMO

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16669428/process-very-large-20gb-text-file-line-by-line

Comment: Reading 50GB of text is going to take a while. You're very likely I/O blocked more than anything else; there's very little you can do algorithmically that will alleviate this. If you have a lot of unique names, you're also going to find that printing to the screen is abominably slow--try piping the output to a file to speed up the output reporting.

Comment: Do you know that there are no identical lines? If there are identical lines, how do you want them counted?

Comment: Why do you call `enumerate`? Wouldn't `for line in f:` suffice?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422507/count-unique-values-per-unique-keys-in-python-dictionary?rq=1)'s accepted answer is identical to what you've started with.

Comment: no there are no identical lines. I already preprocessed that.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use `collections.Counter`. This will double-count identical lines, but it might go faster:

```
import collections

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = collections.Counter(line.split('|',1)[0] for line in f)

print d.most_common(5)
```

Comment: This does not work . I get this error:AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'counter'

Comment: 1) Are you using Python version 2.7 or higher? `collections.Counter` was introduced in 2.7. 2) Are you spelling `Counter` correctly? It starts with a capital `C`, and your error message has a lower-case `c`.